# How to extract the number after strong?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

please tell me how to extract the value after strong (6666666666)

```
<div class="general-section">
<p><strong>Text</strong> TextTextText</p>
<p><strong>Text2</strong> 6666666666</p>
<p><strong>Text3</strong> 1111111111</p>
</div>
```

I try like this:

```
print(soup.select('.general-section :nth-child(2)'))
print(soup.select('.general-section :nth-child(2) > strong.next_sibling'))
```

Sorry, I just started learning parsing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to your goal with the `css selector` but based on your example you have to use `next_sibling` based on your element:

```
html = '''
<div class="general-section">
<p><strong>Text</strong> TextTextText</p>
<p><strong>Text2</strong> 6666666666</p>
<p><strong>Text3</strong> 1111111111</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('.general-section p:nth-child(2) strong').next_sibling.strip()
```

Output:

```
6666666666
```